# MySQL Insert new row based on multiple other rows for every company id

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL database with many companies (several hundred).  For each company I need to insert a single row in a new table that combines data from two rows in another table. Kind of like this:

```
For each company in Companies{
  Get min(AgeInMonths) as YoungestGroup from AgeGroups where companyid = company;
  Get max(AgeInMonths) as OldestGroup from AgeGroups where companyid = company;
  Insert YoungestGroup,OldestGroup,CompanyId into CombinedAgeGroups
}
```

My table structure is (basically) as follows:

**Companies**

- CompanyId
- CompanyName

**AgeGroups**

- AgeGroupId
- CompanyId
- AgeInMonths

**CombinedAgeGroups**

- CompanyId
- YoungestGroupId
- OldestGroupId
- MaxGroupSize

So in the CombinedAgeGroups table I will need to end up with a single row for each company.  How do I loop through all the companies, get the youngest group and the oldest group out of the AgeGroups table for each company, and insert those values into CombinedAgeGroups?

Comment: The names of columns `YoungestGroupId` and `OldestGroupId` in `CombinedAgeGroups` suggest that they ought to be foreign keys into `AgeGroups`, which is not the logic that you describe.  Is your logic correct?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`INSERT ... SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/insert-select.html) with a *grouped* query:

```
INSERT INTO CombinedAgeGroups (
         CompanyId, YoungestGroupId , OldestGroupId
)
SELECT   CompanyId, MIN(AgeInMonths), MAX(AgeInMonths)
FROM     AgeGroups
GROUP BY CompanyId
```

Comment: Thank you.  I ended up writing a temporary PHP script to do it, but it looks like this would have worked as well.

Comment: @Vincent: Fair enough... but given that my answer was posted only 3 minutes after your question was asked, one wonders why you bothered asking!  :)